# The underlying connection was closed. The server committed a protocol violation vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ftpwebrequest, ftp-server, ftpwebresponse

I need help, none i can't seem to find a solution to my problem.

I'm trying to create a directory in FTP Server:

```
Dim request As FtpWebRequest = FtpWebRequest.Create("ftp:\\*******")
        Dim creds As NetworkCredential = New NetworkCredential("****", "*****")
        request.Credentials = creds
        request.KeepAlive = True
        request.EnableSsl = True
        request.UsePassive = True

        request.Timeout = 10000000
        request.ReadWriteTimeout = 10000000
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = New System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AddressOf customCertValidation)

        Dim resp As FtpWebResponse = Nothing
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails

        Using resp
            resp = request.GetResponse()
            Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII)
            Dim s As String = sr.ReadToEnd()
            If Not s.Contains("newfolder") Then

                request = FtpWebRequest.Create("ftp:\\********")
                request.Credentials = creds
                request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.MakeDirectory
                resp = request.GetResponse()
                Console.WriteLine(resp.StatusCode & "Created")
            Else
                Console.WriteLine("Directory already exists")
            End If
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString)
    End Try
```

Function for customCertValidation

```
Function customCertValidation(ByVal sender As Object,
                                            ByVal cert As X509Certificate,
                                            ByVal chain As X509Chain,
                                            ByVal errors As SslPolicyErrors) As Boolean
    Return True
End Function
```

I get the following error:

[image]

I have tried everything on the web but nothing seems to work, can someone please tell me what is wrong. 
Thank You

Comment: You have two calls to `FtpWebRequest.GetResponse` - which is throwing the exception?  One possibility - isn't port 22 SSH, not FTP?  The slashes should also be forward - `ftp://...`, but that seems unlikely to be the issue.

Comment: Port 22 is SFTP, however using ftp open <ip address: Port> allows the connection so we believe the ftp server is allowing both.

Comment: The message "The server committed a protocol violation" may indicate that it doesn't actually support both.  Perhaps try something like [SSH.NET](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET) and see if that works?